# Exchanging arbitrary data between Linux UDP sockets through methods other than payload

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to exchange arbitrary data (few bytes, say 12 or 16) between two Linux UDP sockets without injecting this data into the payload of the message. I want the data to go on the wire with the rest of the packet, but it should be separate from the payload in as much as the receiving application should be able to read the payload without knowing about the extra data.

Methods I have thought of so far but haven't tried yet

1. Ancillary Data
2. IP options field

If you've used those methods successfully, please let me know or even better point me at some code.

Comment: If you used a stream-oriented protocol, you might be able to send out-of-band data. You  can't do this with UDP.

Comment: That's not an option unfortunately. Are you 100% sure this is not possible with UDP? What about the two approaches I mentioned?

Comment: UDP is intended to be the absolute minimum, bare-bones, "send a packet and hope for the best" approach to networking. It does not include cute tricks like multiple separated payloads (like you apparently want).

Comment: I actually never mentioned that this has to be a transport specific feature. IP has options and I'm interested in whether applications can write and read options to use them as a separate communication channel. I always get the feeling people in Stackoverflow jump the gun with dismissing things when they clearly don't have enough information.

Comment: You probably can embed data into the IP options field if you craft packets manually, but I don't know how you would get it back out via a UDP socket.  Ultimately, I think that would mean using raw sockets on both sides, and emulating whatever transport-layer protocol you like, instead of using the built-in UDP layer.

Comment: Sure, if your processes have `CAP_NET_RAW` capabilities. Is this a good idea? No.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't have that option unfortunately.

Comment: You could use the source port to encode a few *bits* per datagram, though. It is typically ignored by the recipients, but trivial to receive.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Do you mean re-bind the socket with every send?

Comment: @Kariem: Kind of, yes, except that I'd pre-bind the UDP sockets beforehand, and just select which socket to use when sending a message.

Comment: @NominalAnimal It's an interesting idea, thanks. I think I might need a bit more space and also it has some implications regarding memory and to some extent re-orderings in a high throughput setup.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Receiving the IP options included in each UDP datagram is actually easy in Linux: set the [IP_RECVOPTS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) socket option before binding the socket, and use `recvmsg()` to receive the messages; the incoming IP options will then be in `IP_OPTIONS` ancillary data. I haven't used this myself, though. For sending, one can set the IP options using the `IP_OPTIONS` socket option, but the *"can only be set by the local user"* sounds weird (only the local end is "sending", here). Needs some testing to verify, I think.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I think that's pretty much what I'm looking for, I will try that and post if it works. Thanks!!

Comment: @Kariem: You should use an actual ethernet connection for testing. I noticed that using the loopback interface (receiving test program listening to my internet-visible IP address, and sending test program sending to that address) the options did not make it. This might be due to the kernel not computing the checksum for UDP packets on the loopback interface (unless otherwise configured; this is a common optimization feature) and dropping the options due to the incorrect checksum. I'm too lazy to check if that is the cause or not, as it is a Friday evening...

Comment: Also, for some reason the control message is of type `IP_RECVOPTS` or `IP_RETOPTS`, not `IP_OPTIONS` as documented, depending on whether you want processed or unprocessed IP header options. (The level is `IPPROTO_IP`, as expected.) Furthermore, I *do* get the control message (when extra IP options are set); it's just that the received control message data is all zeroes. See [man 7 ip](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) and [man 2 setsockopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html).

Comment: Turns out my control message contents being zeroes is a bug in my code. At least `tcpdump -u -e -vvv -XXX` does see the extra header files. I shall shut up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can send the data you want using IP options.  Since the maximum length of IP options (for IPv4) is 40 bytes, this is enough space to put your extra data.

Before sending a packet, make a call to `setsockopt` with `IP_OPTIONS` for the option name, along with a buffer containing the options.

The first byte contains the option type and the second contains the total length of the option (including the first two bytes).

The format of the option type byte is as follows:

- Copied (1 bit):  Set to 1 if the options need to be copied into all fragments of a fragmented packet.
- Option Class (2 bits):  A general options category. 0 is for "control" options, and 2 is for "debugging and measurement". 1, and 3 are reserved.
- Option Number (5 bits):   Specifies an option.

Option number 30 is reserved for experimental purposes, so that's the one you'll want to use.

```
unsigned char options[] = {
    30,    // option type 30 (experimental)
    14,    // option length
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,   // option data
    1,     // option type 1 (no-op, no length field)
    1      // option type 1 (no-op, no length field)
};
if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_OPTIONS, (char *)&options, sizeof(options))== -1) {
    perror("Error setting options");
    close(sock);
}
```

The total length of all options must be a multiple of 4, so in this example where the custom option has length 14, two NO-OP options are added to pad it out.

On Linux, you need to be root to use this option.

When reading packets, you need to set the `IP_RECVOPTS` option to have access to the options:

```
int option = 1;
if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_RECVOPTS, (char *)&option, sizeof(option)) == -1) {
    perror("Error setting IP_RECVOPTS");
    close(sock);
    exit(1);
}
```

Then you would use `recvmsg` instead of `recvfrom` to get to that data:

```
struct sockaddr_in sin_recv;
char mes[1500];
struct msghdr mhdr;
struct iovec iov;
struct cmsghdr *cmhdr;
char control[1000];
int len;
unsigned char *options;
unsigned int i;

mhdr.msg_name = &sin_recv;
mhdr.msg_namelen = sizeof(sin_recv);
mhdr.msg_iov = &iov;
mhdr.msg_iovlen = 1;
mhdr.msg_control = &control;
mhdr.msg_controllen = sizeof(control);
iov.iov_base = mes;
iov.iov_len = sizeof(mes);
if ((len = recvmsg(sock, &mhdr, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Error receiving");
} else {
    cmhdr = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&mhdr);
    while (cmhdr) {
        if (cmhdr->cmsg_level == IPPROTO_IP &&
                cmhdr->cmsg_type == IP_RECVOPTS) {
            options = CMSG_DATA(cmhdr);
            printf("options: ");
            for (i=0;i<cmhdr->cmsg_len-sizeof(struct cmsghdr);i++) {
                printf("%02x ", options[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        cmhdr = CMSG_NXTHDR(&mhdr, cmhdr);
    }
}
```

If you do find options, you'll get all IP options grouped together.  So you would need to further parse the contents of the option data to find your app specific data.

Comment: Could you check if you can actually pass any extra options using the loopback device? (I don't have two machines suitably set up now for testing, and I'm too lazy to set up, so loopback is all I tested.) For me, on x86-64 using a 4.4.0 kernel, I do get the control message, but it is all zeroed out. If you have tested yours and it works, then I know mine has a bug and I should not code on a Friday. :)

Comment: @NominalAnimal Yes, I tested this on a 2.6 kernel sending to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thanks. I did realize I could use `tcpdump -u -e -vvv -XXX ...' and take a look to see if the option payload is visible to the receiver; it is, so my test program is just buggy. Have a nice weekend!