# Read IP_OPTIONS from tcp socket in linux tcp client

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, ip

### Goal

Read ip options from tcp socket in userspace.

### Investigation

I found [Exchanging arbitrary data between Linux UDP sockets through methods other than payload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39298615/4123703) which suggests to use `IP_RECVOPTS` to read the ip options.
Unfotunately it seems that [`IP_RECVOPTS` doesn't support `SOCK_STREAM`(TCP)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html). 
I tried to enabled `IP_RECVOPTS` and tested it but `cmhdr` is always `NULL` in `cmhdr = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&mhdr);`

It should be straightforward but I cannot find any posts relates to it.. Did I miss anything?

By the way `getsockopt` with `IP_OPTIONS` provides the *settings* of ip options of a socket, not the received ip options in traffic.

### Keywords

- linux read ip options from tcp server 
  --> Nothing related
- linux read IP_OPTIONS TCP 
  --> Nothing related

### Test code..

Sorry they're walls of text..

Sample code is modified from [smallbomb's server client example](https://github.com/smallbomb/-Linux-C-sample-socket)

#### Compile commands

```
g++ -g -Wall -ansi clientsocket.c -o clientsocket
g++ -g -Wall -ansi serversocket.c -o serversocket
```

#### To test it

`sudo ./serversocket`
`sudo ./clientsocket`

#### clientsocket.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define buffersize 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 
    //int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP); doesn't help to read IP_OPTIONS as well..
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    
    // Ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/39298615/4123703
    unsigned char options[] = {
        30,    // option type 30 (experimental)
        14,    // option length
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,   // option data
        1,     // option type 1 (no-op, no length field)
        1      // option type 1 (no-op, no length field)
    };
    // unsigned char options[40] = {1};
    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_OPTIONS, (char *)&options, sizeof(options))== -1) {
        perror("Error setting options");
        close(sock);
    }
    // This set doesn't support SOCK_STREAM, refer to
    // https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html section IP_RECVOPTS
    int option = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_RECVOPTS, (char *)&option, sizeof(option)) == -1) {
        perror("Error setting IP_RECVOPTS");
        close(sock);
     exit(1);
    }
    
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5566);
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    const char *message = "11";
    printf("send\n");
    send(sock, message, strlen(message)+1, 0);
    printf("send done\n");
   { // Since IP_RECVOPTS isn't supported, `cmhdr` is always NULL
      // just put it here to prove that it's not supported
      struct sockaddr_in sin_recv;
      char mes[1500];
      struct msghdr mhdr;
      struct iovec iov;
      struct cmsghdr *cmhdr;
      char control[1000];
      int len;
      unsigned char *recv_options;
      unsigned int i;

      mhdr.msg_name = &sin_recv;
      mhdr.msg_namelen = sizeof(sin_recv);
      mhdr.msg_iov = &iov;
      mhdr.msg_iovlen = 1;
      mhdr.msg_control = &control;
      mhdr.msg_controllen = sizeof(control);
      iov.iov_base = mes;
      iov.iov_len = sizeof(mes);
      if ((len = recvmsg(sock, &mhdr, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Error receiving");
    } else {
        cmhdr = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&mhdr); // In SOCK_STREAM, `cmhdr` is always NULL
        printf("cmhdr address %p\n", cmhdr);
        while (cmhdr) {
            if (cmhdr->cmsg_level == IPPROTO_IP &&
                    cmhdr->cmsg_type == IP_RECVOPTS) {
                recv_options = CMSG_DATA(cmhdr);
                printf("options: ");
                for (i=0;i<cmhdr->cmsg_len-sizeof(struct cmsghdr);i++) {
                    printf("%02x ", recv_options[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            cmhdr = CMSG_NXTHDR(&mhdr, cmhdr);
        }
    }
    }

    char *buffer = (char*) calloc(buffersize, sizeof(char)) ;
    printf("read\n");
    read(sock, buffer, buffersize);

    printf("result form server: %s\n", buffer);

    free(buffer);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

#### server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define buffersize 1024

void sig_fork(int signo) {
    int stat;
    waitpid(0, &stat, WNOHANG);
    return;
}

int main(){
    printf("pid %d\n", getpid()) ;
    signal(SIGCHLD, sig_fork); 
    int serv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    printf("serv_sock fd %d\n", serv_sock);
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 5; // sec
    timeout.tv_usec = 0; // ms

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;  
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");  
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5566);  
    bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    listen(serv_sock, 20);

    struct sockaddr_in clnt_addr;
    socklen_t clnt_addr_size = sizeof(clnt_addr);

    while (1) {
      int clnt_sock = accept(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&clnt_addr, &clnt_addr_size);

      // //  Ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/39298615/4123703
      unsigned char options[] = {
          30, // option type 30 (experimental)
          14, // option length
          11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, // option data
          1, // option type 1 (no-op, no length field)
          1  // option type 1 (no-op, no length field)
      };
      printf("size %lu", sizeof(options));
      if (setsockopt(clnt_sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_OPTIONS, (char *)&options,
                     sizeof(options)) == -1) {
        perror("Error setting after socket created");
        // printf("%d", errno);
        close(serv_sock);
        close(clnt_sock);
        return -1;
      }

      // set recv and send timeout
      printf("accepted\n");
      if( setsockopt (clnt_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0 )
        printf( "setsockopt fail\n" );
      if( setsockopt (clnt_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0 )
        printf( "setsockopt fail\n" ) ;

      int pid = fork();
      if (pid == -1) {
        printf( "ERROR pid\n" );
      } 
       
      else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("pid %d\n", getpid()) ;
        char *buffer = (char*) calloc(buffersize, sizeof(char));
        recv(clnt_sock, buffer, buffersize, 0) ;

        printf("Server receive:%s\n", buffer) ;
        int total = (int)(atoi(buffer)*atoi(buffer)) ;
        printf("Server return num^2:%d\n", total) ;
        char *returnvalue = (char*) calloc(buffersize, sizeof(char));
        sprintf( returnvalue, "result:%d", total ) ;

        send(clnt_sock, returnvalue, buffersize, 0) ;
        close(clnt_sock) ;
        close(serv_sock) ;
        return 0 ;
      } 
      else {
        close(clnt_sock);
      }
    }    
       
    close(serv_sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: since TCP doesn't pass all the packets to userspace - not every packet generates a recv call - and a single packet may generate multiple recv calls - which packet's options would you expect to read?

Comment: @user253751, I want to read a custom ip options which is used between client and server ( written by myself ). I was working on a POC and found this issue. Your comment explains why there is little info related to this topic.

Comment: @user253751 do you know if `getsockopt` with `IP_OPTIONS` working on retrieving the received ip options? Because I tried it but it always replied "bad address"..

Comment: IP options can be different on every packet so I don't know how this would make any sense. The kernel wouldn't know which packet to get the options from. It's even possible that it hasn't received *any* packets yet.

Comment: @user253751 Got it, thanks for clarification. I just came across `getsockopt` and I'm not sure if it used in such case.